# Why douuble pole switch must be used for water heater?

Tags: switch

I read from some notes stating that 1 way double-pole switch must be used for fixed heating appliance where heating element can be touched.
What is the rational behind that?

Comment: "Switch"? Or breaker?

Answer (score 3):

Most water heaters are 240v, this voltage is created by using 2 hot legs, for a local disconnect or breaker both hots need to be disconnected. If a single pole was used as the local disconnect the water heater would not heat but there would still be 120v at the control to the elements and this creates a hazard to someone working on the water heater (like when time to change the elements). If it is a 120v water heater a single pole is acceptable (these are usually smaller under sink type where only a small amount of water is needed at a remote location from the main water heater).

Answer (score 1):

Because in a 240 volt circuit, both wires are "hot", but opposite phases. With a regular SPST switch, only one of the wires will be disconnected when the switch is turned off. That will turn off the heating element, but it will not de-energize it. Anyone that touches the element (or its wiring terminals) and touches something else grounded will get shocked.

The correct way to wire a disconnect is to interrupt all wires that are not at ground potential.

Comment: Funny that sounds. Like what I said.